# I am not able to understand how *ngFor is iterating through heroes array

Tags: angular, ngfor

[output should be like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaZeN.png)
output of the program should be like in this screenshot. Why {{hero}} instead of {{heroes}} as my array name is heroes ??

```
template: `
      <h1>{{title}}</h1>
      <h2>My favorite hero is: {{myHero}}</h2>
      <p>Heroes:</p>
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes"> 
          {{ hero }}
        </li>
      </ul>
    `
    export class AppComponent  { name = 'Angular';
     title : string ;
     heroes = ['Windstorm','Bombasto','Magneta','Tornado'];
      myhero = this.heroes[0] ; 

    constructor()
    {
    this.title = 'Tour Of Heroes';
    }
    }
```

Comment: `let hero` <= because of that. `hero` is the the value of the current element being processed in the `heroes` array.

Comment: _The let hero part of the expression identifies hero as the template input variable, which holds the current hero item for each iteration. You can reference this variable within the template to access the current hero's properties._ From the [Tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt2#list-heroes-with-ngfor)

Comment: please read about iteration, foreach, etc...

Answer (score 1):

`let hero` <= because of that. `hero` is the the value of the current element being processed in the `heroes` array.

See also [NgForOf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf) documentation and [Foreach Loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreach_loop) information for the basics.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the asterix-syntax of a directive (in this case the [`ngForOf`-directive](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf)).

The asterix-syntax is translated the following way:

**1** The `*` in front of the directive selector `ngFor` wraps the element into a `ng-template`.

```
<ng-template [ngFor]="let hero of heroes">
  <li>
    {{ hero }}
  </li>
</ng-template>
```

---

**2** The `let variableName` creates a local template variable with the name `variableName` for the `implicit$` context:

```
<ng-template [ngFor]="of heroes" let-hero>
  <li>
    {{ hero }}
  </li>
</ng-template>
```

---

**3** The string between the variable declaration and the input, in this case it's `of` is appended to the directive selector:

```
<ng-template [ngForOf]="heroes" let-hero>
  <li>
    {{ hero }}
  </li>
</ng-template>
```

In step **2** the `let hero` is translated to `let-hero`, therefore you can use the local template variable `hero` inside your template, the [**ngForOf**](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf) directive binds the current array element to it.